# How to convert this logic from LabVIEW to C# - hex string to byte array and type cast the byte array to single

Tags: c#, labview

LabVIEW code:

[image: hex string is converted in to byte array then it is typecast to single]

C# code I tried:

```
var freqArray = new byte[] { 67, 179, 84, 45 };  

// 358.658

var r1 = BitConverter.ToDouble(freqArray, 0);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ;-) I am not sure if I understood your question correctly but if you want to convert a specific hexadecimal value into a decimal value you can use [`Int32.Parse(String, NumberStyles)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=net-5.0#System_Int32_Parse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_) for that. Something like `int.Parse(number, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);` should do the trick... You would have to handle multiple hex-numbers in the string of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you are dealing with a 4 byte values and `double` require 8 bytes. What you want is using `single` as it's a 4 bytes.

```
var r1 = BitConverter.ToSingle(freqArray, 0);
```

Secondly your array is backward and it should be :

```
var freqArray = new byte[] { 45, 84 , 179, 67 };
```